# Is it possible to get the rendered view output from a Phalcon controller? From within a unit test?

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm writing a controller test, like so:

```
class DepositOrderTest extends AbstractUnitTest {
    public function testTestCase(): void {
        $deposit_controller = new DepositController();
        $deposit_controller->setDI($this->di);
        $result = $deposit_controller->indexAction();
        error_log($result);
    }
}
```

I was hoping that `$result` might be the HTML output, but it is not. How do I get the HTML output of this action? Is it even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in short you can use `Phalcon\Mvc\View\Simple` to render views without hierarchical levels

```php
use Phalcon\Mvc\View\Simple;

$view = new Simple();

$view->setViewsDir('../app/views/');

echo $view->render('templates/welcome');

echo $view->render(
    'templates/welcome',
    [
        'email'   => $email,
        'content' => $content,
    ]
);
```

or you can check the [documentation](https://docs.phalcon.io/4.0/en/views#stand-alone) for other/complex options

Comment: I'd like to be able to test in tandem with the controller function, is that not possible?

Comment: ```$view->render('users/edit')``` this would return the view partial ```views/users/edit.phtml``` if you are using ```.phtml``` engine and you change what is needed. for example you can register the engines using ```Phalcon\Mvc\View\Simple::registerEngines(array $engines)```. i would suggest taking a look at the api in documentation and if its not clear the class source on github